# Git Fetch vs Git Fetch Origin

Tags: git, version-control

I wanted to fetch a single remote branch and then rebase my current working branch against that as I am sharing it with someone. Usually I would just do:

`git fetch`

`git rebase origin/branch_im_working_on`

That seems to work ok but it appears to fetch all branches from the remote repository. So I looked around and found this:

`git fetch origin branch_im_working_on`

When I do this git tells me it fetched HEAD and then try to do:

`git rebase origin/branch_im_working_on`

git tells me that I am up to date and there is nothing to do even though I know there are changes pushed to remote.

If I try to do:

`git rebase origin branch_im_working_on`

I get a lot of merge conflicts so had to resort back to the original commands to get my branch up to date:

`git fetch`

`git rebase origin\branch_im_working_on`

Can someone help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: `git rebase origin\branch_im_working_on` will rebase your local with its counterpart on origin. SO if both are in sync then there is nothing to do. Are you sure that fetch happened successfully? And that the origin version  is head of yours?

Comment: I thought it did because it told me it fetched HEAD but maybe it didnt actually fetch anything? I guess omitting the 'origin' from git fetch and just using the branch name alone is the same?

Comment: Well, if you have just one remote which is `origin`, you shouldn't have any problems, you can check it with `git remote -v`. That will list the remotes you have. Also you can check what you fetched, by looking at the log of `origin/your_branch`

Comment: `git fetch origin <branch> && git rebase FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: @ElpieKay, But, `FETCH_HEAD` should be the same as `refs/remotes/origin/his_branch/HEAD` right?

Comment: Is that just a one liner for the two commands? My output from git remote -v is: origin git@git:/opt/git/dev (fetch)
origin git@git:/opt/git/dev (push)

Comment: that's just one remote, it means to say you are using the same remote to both push and pull. As, git allows you to push to one and pull from another :)

Comment: @anchreg Not always. If `remote.origin.fetch` is not specified or the ref spec is different with the default, `remotes/origin/xxx` won't be created or updated. But `FETCH_HEAD` is always there and updated by last `git fetch`, including `git pull`.

Comment: @ElpieKay so if your one liner does both and always ensures that the rebase should work then I think I will just start using that from now on. I guess the last thing I want to know is what is the diff between `git rebase origin my_branch` and `git rebase origin/my_branch`, if any? The reason I ask is that I got 2 different outcomes from the 2 commands.

Comment: `git fetch origin/my_branch` should echo error in most cases unless you really have a remote named `origin/my_branch`. In `git fetch origin my_branch`, `origin` is a remote, an alias of the url to the remote repository like `https://github.com/my/test.git`. With a remote, you build a link between your local repository and a remote repository. In this case `git fetch https://github.com/my/test.git my_branch` also works but you can use `origin` to type much fewer words. `origin` is the default remote when you clone a repository. You can add, delete, rename and edit one or more remotes.

Comment: Sorry I had retyped my comment, I meant `git rebase origin my_branch` and `git rebase origin/my_branch`

Comment: Sorry. You asked about `git rebase`. Then `git rebase origin my_branch` should echo error in most cases unless you have two local branches `origin` and `my_branch`. Not sure if `origin` is a valid branch when a remote `origin` exists. The arguments after `git rebase` should be branches or commits. `git rebase <branch>` is equivalent to `git rebase <branch> <current-branch>`.

Comment: Yes thats similar to what Marina Liu has said below but oddly I am able to do that and have been doing it for some time to rebase. I also did `git log origin/feature/my_branch` and I get the log for this, minus my unpushed changes which are at the top of the branch feature/my_branch when I do `git log feature/my_branch`. I am not sure what is going on there then but it appears it shouldnt work but does!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Differences between `git fetch` and `git fetch origin`

- If the git repo only has one remote `origin` (you can check remotes by `git remote -v`), the two commands work as same.
- If the git repo contains more than one remotes, such as there has remotes `origin` and `upstream`. `git fetch` will fetch all the changes from the remotes `origin` and `upstream`. `git fetch origin` will only fetch the changes from remote `origin`.

Beside, if you only want to fetch a certain branch from a remote, you can use `git fetch remotename branchname`. Such as `git fetch origin branch_im_working_on` will only fetch the changes from origin `branch_im_working_on`.

### Rebase your local changes on the top on the remote branch:

Assume the commit history looks as below after fetching:

```
…---A---B---C---D  branch_im_working_on
         \
          E---F   origin/branch_im_working_on
```

If you want your local changes (commit `C` and commit `D`) on the top on the `origin/branch_im_working_on` (latest commit), any one of the below commands can work as seems:

```
git rebase origin branch_im_working_on
git rebase origin/branch_im_working_on
git fetch origin branch_im_working_on --rebase
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
…---A---B---E---F---C---D  branch_im_working_on
                |
     origin/branch_im_working_on
```

But **the command `git rebase origin\branch_im_working_on` can not be work (for windows OS)** since `origin\branch_im_working_on` is not a valid branch (neither local branch nor tracking branch).

Comment: "But the command git rebase origin\branch_im_working_on can not be work since origin\branch_im_working_on is not a valid branch" everything else you said makes sense except this. I just did that and my branch IS now rebased against origin, further more I just tried `git log origin/feature/my_branch` and I get the git log for it, minus my rebased changes which are applied to the top of my tracking feature branch of the same name.

Comment: What's the OS do you use? At least  \ and / are sensitive for windows. If you are using windows, you will find the command `git rebase origin\branchname` is invalid.

Comment: The operating system is Centos

Comment: I get what you mean now, I just flipped the slash as I dont use windows!

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't liunx OS. But I added the claim it's for windows. Thank's for your reminder :)

Comment: Np thanks for the in depth answer and for pointing out the mistake in my question! I have edited my post to invert the slash so it is correct.

Comment: _"git fetch will fetch all the changes from the remotes origin and upstream. git fetch origin will only fetch the changes from remote origin"_ - this is incorrect, the documentation says: _"When no remote is specified, by default the origin remote will be used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current branch."_